# What is this small "widget" in this flutter example?

Tags: flutter

I am looking at this tutorial: https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/.

The [example code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/_includes/code/layout/tapbox-c/main.dart) for "A mix-and-match approach" has some small "widget". What is this small "widget"?

I printed it and it showed "TapboxC". Why is that? Any reference that explains this that I must have missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it's here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/widget.html

https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/ has some explanation too:

> To access properties of the current ShoppingList, the _ShoppingListState can use its widget property. If the parent rebuilds and creates a new ShoppingList, the _ShoppingListState will also rebuild with the new widget value